# Referring to Hydra's `conf` directory from a Python sub/sub-sub-directory module

Tags: python, path, config, fb-hydra

Suppose that we have a Python project with this structure:

```
hydra_config
├── conf
│   ├── api_key
│   │   ├── non_prod.yaml
│   │   └── prod.yaml
│   └── db
│       ├── mysql.yaml
│       └── postgresql.yaml
├── modules
│   └── module.py
└── my_app.py
```

Now, in Hydra's config documentation, they state that we need to add a Python decorator on top of a function which we want to give access to the configuration files. However, the docs only showed how to do this to a function in `my_app.py` which is the main module of the project.

The question is, how would one add the

```
@hydra.main(config_path="conf")
```

Python decorator to a function, let's say `module_function` which is located in `modules/module.py`? Here's the content of `module.py`:

```
import hydra
from omegaconf import DictConfig, OmegaConf

@hydra.main(config_path="conf")
def module_function(cfg: DictConfig):
    print(OmegaConf.to_yaml(cfg))
```

And then below is the content of the main Python module `my_app.py`:

```
from modules.module import module_function

def main():
    module_function()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I tried running the main Python module **`my_app.py`** with **`python my_app.py`**, I instantly got an error saying

```
Primary config module 'modules.conf' not found.
Check that it's correct and contains an __init__.py file

Set the environment variable HYDRA_FULL_ERROR=1 for a complete stack trace.
```

I understand that this means the decorator added to `module_function` inside `module.py` couldn't find the `conf` directory which contains **api_key** and **db** config groups.

Does anyone here have any experience with this and know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 7):

First I'll go over some possible solutions, then I'll give an explanation.
Here are three things you can do to make your example work:

###### Fix 1: create `conf/__init__.py` and change `config_path="conf"` to `config_path="../conf"`:

```
├── conf
│   ├── config.yaml
│   └── __init__.py
├── modules
│   └── module.py
└── my_app.py
```

```py
# modules/module.py
import hydra
from omegaconf import DictConfig, OmegaConf

@hydra.main(config_path="../conf", config_name="config")  # relative path
def module_function(cfg: DictConfig):
    print(OmegaConf.to_yaml(cfg))
```

###### Fix 2: move `conf` to `modules/conf` and create `modules/conf/__init__.py`:

```py
├── modules
│   ├── conf
│   │   ├── config.yaml
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── module.py
└── my_app.py
```

###### Fix 3: define your decorated function in the module that will be called as `__main__`:

```py
├── conf
│   └── config.yaml
└── my_app.py
```

```py
# my_app.py
import hydra
from omegaconf import DictConfig, OmegaConf

@hydra.main(config_path="conf", config_name="config")
def module_function(cfg: DictConfig):
    print(OmegaConf.to_yaml(cfg))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    module_function()
```

Fix 3 will not be very satisfying to the OP :)

### Explanation

In your example, since you've imported the decorated function (rather than defining it in the `__main__` module), Hydra is interpreting the argument `config_path="conf"` as being relative to the parent of the module that defines the decorated function. In your example, the decorated function is defined in `modules.module`, whose parent is `modules`, so Hydra is looking for a python package called `modules.conf`. If found, this package will be searched for yaml files.

Fix 2 above takes the approach of making sure that `modules/conf/__init__.py` exists, so that `modules.conf` is in-fact a python package.
Meanwhile, Fix 1 takes the approach of using a relative path `config_path="../conf"`. Hydra then looks for a top-level package named `conf`. Since `conf/__init__.py` exists, this top-level `conf` package is found and searched for yaml files. To discover this package, Hydra uses the python import machinery. This means Hydra has the ability to discover yaml files located in python packages that are elsewhere on your `$PYTHONPATH` or that are installed via a package manager such as `pip`.

In the case of Fix 3, we have `module_function.__module__ == "__main__"`, which means that Hydra cannot rely on python's import machinery to discover where `module_function` was defined. As a fallback, Hydra tries to find a *directory* `conf` (rather than a *package* `conf`); this is why an `__init__.py` file is not required for Fix 3. [Here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/blob/f1118812efa6e76f9df3146a082fbff996c442d4/hydra/_internal/utils.py#L47-L52) are the key lines of code implementing this behavior. Note that `conf` is still treated as a relative path, relative to the directory containing the *file* that defined the decorated function (rather than to the parent of the *module* that defined it). [Here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/blob/f1118812efa6e76f9df3146a082fbff996c442d4/hydra/_internal/utils.py#L115-L156) is the function implementating this relative path computation (for both the module case and the directory case).